# Can I make my VBScript program ignore a field when reading from Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vbscript

I did a little bit of reading on what I am about to ask, but I couldn't find a specific answer.

I am writing a program in VBScript that will read an excel file and then update an Access Database.

It works great, but the problem I can foresee running into is thus:

What happens when the excel file has a blank on a specified field? I don't want the script file to update a "blank" to the database, I want it to be left unchanged in the database ONLY if there is a blank in the excel file. If not, proceed as normal.

Currently, it will read this as a blank and insert the blank into the row in my database.

Is this possible? For the script to basically ignore fields it reads (in Excel) that are blank while only updating (in the database) the fields that actually have data (in Excel) in them?

Currently, it says no in the field in the database. This is just a brief code example. In the Excel sheet, it says yes in the correct column.

```
Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
 asset_Tag = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
 ebay = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
 intRow = intRow + 1

objRecordSet.Open "UPDATE Test SET Listed_Ebay = '" & ebay & "' WHERE Asset_Tag = '" & asset_Tag & "'", _
    objConnection
Loop
```

Comment: Would you just use an "if" condition to check the values you care about before executing the insert?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF I was thinking that, but I don't want to have to write an If statement for every field. There will be nearly 20 fields once it is all said and done.

Comment: Depending on how the rows are being read/handled, you could probably have some code that is more elegant than 20 if statements.  To the comment above, you really need to show your code if you want any more specific input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reluctant to add 20 `If` statements to your code, surely you could put Excel's native `COUNTA` functionality to make sure that there are 20 values before the update operation.

```
With objExcel
  Do Until .Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    If .Application.CountA(.Cells(intRow, 1).Resize(1, 20)) = 20 Then
      asset_Tag = .Cells(intRow, 1).Value
      ebay = .Cells(intRow, 2).Value
      objRecordSet.Open "UPDATE Test SET Listed_Ebay = '" & ebay & "' WHERE Asset_Tag = '" & asset_Tag & "'", objConnection
    End if
    intRow = intRow + 1
  Loop
End With
```

I had a guess a bit as to *which* 20 values were intended to be filled but I think you can get the idea.

**EDIT NOTE¹:** reordered the code lines to maintain the *intRow* according to the loop.

**EDIT NOTE²:** You may want to conditionally pass the original value back into the `UPDATE` query if the `LEN` of the new value is zero.

```
Dim qry as String
qry = "UPDATE Test SET " & _
         "Listed_Ebay = Iif(CBool(Len('" & ebay & "')), '" & ebay & "', Listed_Ebay), " & _
         "Listed_Amazon = Iif(CBool(Len('" & amzon& "')), '" & amzon & "', Listed_Amazon), " & _
         "Listed_POS = Iif(CBool(Len('" & pos& "')), '" & pos & "', Listed_POS) " & _
      "WHERE Asset_Tag = '" & asset_Tag & "'"
objRecordSet.Open qry, objConnection
```

I'm just making stuff up past the original one field example you provided but you should be able to transcribe this for your own 8 fields. I'm using `LEN` here on text values but comparing numbers to zero (or even their `LEN` would be appropriate.

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what I was looking for. Any suggestions on how I would adjust my syntax if say only 8 of the 20 fields had data in them, only putting those 8 values alone into the database?

Comment: @amoyer - If you are going to try picking and choosing which fields dictate an update, you may have to resort to many `If` statements.

Comment: @amoyer - Please review the above addition to see if that is appropriate for your 8 field conditions.